# Finding all accumulation points of this set

Tags: limits, analysis

I am looking for all accumulation points of the set $M = \{\frac{k}{m} \mid k,m \in \mathbb N, k\le m \} $.

I want to do this by using the fact that some $x$ is an accumulation point if and only if there is a sequence in $M$ (without $x$) that converges towards $x$ in infinity.

Looking at $M$, I got the idea that the set $M \cup \{0\}$ must include all accumulation points of M.

For zero, I think its quite easy to see because $(x_n)=\frac{1}{n}\subset M$ (without zero) converges to zero for n towards infinity. Thus, zero is an accumulation point of M.
Now I thought that one can construct sequences like: $(a_n)=\frac{k}{m}-\frac{1}{n+1} \in M$(without $\frac{k}{m}$). Obviously  $(a_n)$ converges towards $ \frac{k}{m}$ for n towards infinity. Thus  $\frac{k}{m}$ are accumulation points of $M$.

Am I right? Can somebody have a look?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I guess it's $[0,1]$ since $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Use the fact that the rationals are dense in the reals.

Comment: But how can I show that there aren’t more accumulation points than [0,1]?